# How to fix this bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this JSfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/jy93J/1/

have I the problem that when Save is clicked, it replaces "Details" with "0".

If I comment this line

```
$(this).prev().html(order);
```

it doesn't do it any longer, but then sorting doesn't work. Try clicking on "Signed" to sort.

When Save is clicked this is executed

```
$('form').live('submit', function() {
    return false;
});
```

What causes "Details" to "0"?

And how can that be fixed, so sorting still works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector `'#accTable input` includes `<input value="Save" type="submit">`.

Add `:checkbox` to the selector to only select `input` elements that are checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

I updated your fiddle to fix the problem.

In the click function, you were including both buttons and check boxes since you had just input. Once you append :checkbox it stops this from executing the event on the save button, which is what was putting 0 in the element before it (details link).

```
$('#accTable input:checkbox').click(function() {
    var order = this.checked ? '1' : '0';
    $(this).prev().html(order);

    $(this).parents("table").trigger("update");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HH8nk/1/

Answer (score 1):

You are pointing to all HTML input elements, here: save button and checkbox.

Change

```
$('#accTable input').click(function() {
```

to

```
$('#accTable input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
```

and it will work just fine.